# In C#, writing text in to lables

Tags: c#

The name of the `label` that I want to write text in too can be changed depending on some condition. For example, I have 20 labels, but I may want to write my text in to the first 5 or 6 labels.

```
label1.Text = "1st result";
label2.Text = "2nd result";
label3.Text = "3rd result";
```

Instead of naming `label2`, `label3`, is there a way I can change the last digit of the label? For example, something like

```
label[i].Text = "2nd result";//i will hold the value 2
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/array

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Label> labels = somePanel.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
labels[i] = "whatever";
```

You can access the Labels via their parent container.

Comment: This is boss... in my opinion its good practice to implement interfaces `IList<Label>`

Answer (score 2):

Use array of `Label`:

```
Label[] labels = new Label[] { label1, label2, label3 };
```

Then you can do

```
labels[i].Text = "2nd result"; //i will hold the value 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Same using lists:

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
labels.AddRange(new Label[] { new Label(), new Label() });
```

Then access with index

```
labels[i].Text = "yourOne";
```